# How can the final incarnation of the Anti-Christ be prevented from shattering creation?

Tags: religion, gods

After Yahweh defeated Lucifer in the Great War in Heaven, he cast him and his followers into the bowels of hell, there to spend eternity separated from their brethren. However, Yahweh was arrogantly secure in his own power. Now known as Satan, the fallen angel corrupted the human race and influenced it into committing evil sins. God is very particular about who he accepts into heaven, ordering them to live according to his rules. In making it very difficult to enter his kingdom after death, he unwittingly guaranteed that the vast majority of humans to an eternity in hell, giving Satan access to them. This would allow Satan to feed on the souls sent to his realm, making him more powerful. Satan performed his master stroke through his servant, Judas,  the greatest hero of the bible. The sleeper agent apostle bravely betrayed his messiah, removing one of God's valuable pieces from the chessboard. Before he died, Judas wrote a book called the revelations, in which he spoke of the Anti-Christ being born into the realm of man and usher in an age of darkness. This would ultimately culminate in a second War of Heaven, in which Yahweh will be defeated and Satan would reign supreme over all of creation.

However, this prophecy wasn't entirely correct, because the plan worked too well. Gauging himself on the souls being sent to him over thousands of years, Satan had gained far more power than he had anticipated, which ironically presented two problems. His consciousness had become so massive that it wouldn't be able to fit into one physical form. Even if he managed to cross over into the mortal realm, reality wouldn't be able to contain his power, and would shatter creation. To prevent this, he incarnated himself into seven human avatars, each sharing a piece of his consciousness. These avatars later combined themselves, uniting the pieces of Satan into one and restoring him to full strength. With Satan restored, he now began plans for his conquest of Earth and the eventual goal of taking the throne of Heaven.

The first problem of getting into reality can be explained, but leaven open the question of why Satan's power didn't overload and break reality in his final form. How can I explain this away?

Comment: Satan went to his favorite hardware store and bought a suitable overload protection device. Satan went to power management training and learned to contain his power. Satan was scammed into joining the Church of Scientology and they billed him nine tenths of his power as a fee for auditing and progress towards clearness. God sent a beautiful angeless, and Satan spent all his powers at Tiffany's buying baubles for her. Satan had enough of Hell and powers, resigned and went to LA to open a bar. Satan had a son with Lilith, and the son castrated him with a diamond sickle, draining his powers.

Answer (score 1):

#### They don't combine until after Earth is conquered. Because in this case, 7 parts are greater than 1

What's a stronger force?

- Satan on Earth in human form, with the power of 100 billion souls behind him.

  - (100 billion is my estimate for total number of humans who have died in history.)
- 7 small satans, each with the power of 14 billion souls.

I'd argue 7 individuals are stronger than one. They can divide the Earth into 7 regions geographically and conquer them in parallel; but I think more interestingly; 7 different fields.

Give each 1/7th of Satan their own source of sin; For example:

- One takes over Feras Antoon (Owner of like every porn site). The Lust demon.
- One takes over a populist leader and misdirects their nationalism into violence - The Pride demon.
- One takes over Mortimer J. Buckley - CEO of the largest investment firm of the planet. The greed demon.
- One takes over Zuckerberg and makes us spend more time looking at how great the lives of everyone else is - The Envy demon
- One takes over Chris Kempczinski - CEO of McDonalds. The Gluttony demon.
- One takes over Suzanne Scott - Ceo of a large content provider which makes viewers angry - The Wrath demon
- One takes over Dara Khosrowshahi - ceo of a company that brings us everything we want so we don't even have to cook. The Sloth demon.

These 7 demons corrupt Earth by amplifying the 7 forces of darkness, making the final conquest of Earth trivial.

Answer (score 1):

**Entropy.**

Each step in the process is phenomenally wasteful of consciousness energy.  Projecting into the 7 avatars is wasteful.  Containing in the 7 avatars is wasteful as they are leaky containers.  Recombining is terrifically wasteful.  The end product is reduced by orders of magnitude from what there initially was.

Satan does not care.  As OP points out, all that extra energy was an unwanted byproduct and not needed to achieve his ends.

A question for the fiction: energy lost to entropy is lost as heat.  How does consciousness energy lost to entropy affect the system in which it is lost?